# Error by changing all the date format in R

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to change the format from all the dates in one column. I tried it with strftime, as.Date and with parse_date, all giving me some sort of issue. The column includes 2200 different times currently expressed in the following format: Feb-03-2022, it should be expressed as: "%B %d %Y", how could I modify all dates?

```
ethereum <- read_csv('ethereum_2022-01-04_2022-02-03.csv')
head(ethereum)
# Changing date format in the dataset
ethereum$Date <- parse_date(ethereum$`Date`, "%d-%b-%y")
head(ethereum$Date)
# Naming the datatype and the timeseries 
ds<- ethereum$Date
y<- ethereum$`Close`
df<- data.frame(ds,y)
View(df)
```

When I try with this code, I get the following error:

```
Warning: 2200 parsing failures.
row col           expected      actual
  1  -- date like %d-%b-%y Feb-03-2022
  2  -- date like %d-%b-%y Feb-02-2022
  3  -- date like %d-%b-%y Feb-01-2022
  4  -- date like %d-%b-%y Jan-31-2022
  5  -- date like %d-%b-%y Jan-30-2022
... ... .................. ...........
See problems(...) for more details.
```

Comment: `"%d"` is day of the month, but your strings start with "Mon" (abbreviated month name). See `?strptime` for the `%`-codes. (Hint: `"%b-%d-%Y"` should work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the vector to the date format and then apply any desired formatting.

```
vec_str <- c("Feb-03-2022", "Feb-02-2022", "Jan-31-2022", "Jan-30-2022")
vec_dates <- as.Date(x = vec_str, format = "%b-%d-%Y")
vec_dates_str <- format(vec_dates, "%B %d %y")
vec_dates_str
# [1] "February 03 22" "February 02 22" "January 31 22"  "January 30 22"
```

For convenience of applying in data frame you can wrap this behaviour in a function:

```
my_date_transform <- function(x,date_in_format = "%b-%d-%Y",
                              date_out_format = "%B-%d-%Y") {
    x_dates <- as.Date(x = x, format = date_in_format)
    format(x = vec_dates, date_out_format)
  }

my_date_transform(x = vec_str)
```

### Example

```
sample_data <- data.frame(original_date_str = vec_str)
sample_data$new_date_format <- my_date_transform(sample_data$original_date_str)
sample_data
# >> sample_data
# original_date_str  new_date_format
# 1       Feb-03-2022 February-03-2022
# 2       Feb-02-2022 February-02-2022
# 3       Jan-31-2022  January-31-2022
# 4       Jan-30-2022  January-30-2022
```

You can then apply your function to a data frame

Comment: This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are having a packages problem.

Try this example:

```
library(parsedate)

## Calling the function
parse_date("Feb-03-2022")

## Specifying the package to avoid masked functions
parsedate::parse_date("Feb-03-2022")
```

In your code would look like this:

```
ethereum$Date <- parse_date(ethereum$Date)
```

The package "parsedate", is used to parse from any date format. I don't know if all the 2.2k are in the same format, so my suggestion is to use that. In case you are 100% sure, you can use many other parsing date functions. You can even write one yourself using string processing techniques.

Comment: I tried it, but it replaced every date in the column to "Feb-03-2020", it does not matter which date is it. I faced the same issue with strptime and as.Date, do I need to write every single date for it to work?

Comment: No no, was just an example for you. 
As i don't know what library you are using, I suggested that. I will update the post using you code, only replace the part I use